# Microservice: Service must not WRITE messages to topic of other service

Tags: microservices

> Microservice: Service must not WRITE messages to topic of other service.

Is that statement right? What are the pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you share a topic between multiple services then multiple services will be impacted when that topic crashes or is brought down for maintenance. You will also probably introduce a shared library in the messaging client. On the pros , one less topic to administer.

Comment: Yes, we should not share database, topic among microservices.  Only service that owns that topic/database should WRITE to that topic.